# Want to fetch data from roles, in which given accountId is present. (Javasscript, MongoDb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await, loopback3

Roles data model:-

```
Roles : {
    id: string,
    scopes: [
        {
         isOwnes: bool, 
         account: string(id), 
         privileges: array_of_string
        }
    ]
}
```

In the below function I am storing all users, which is a lot of space and time-consuming.

```
User.subUsers = async function(accessToken, cb) {
    const accountId = accessToken.accountId;
    let userData = [];
    const user = await User.find();
    for (let it = 0; it < user.length; it++) {
      const roleData = await User.app.models.roles.findById(user[it].roleId);
      for (let iterator = 0; iterator < roleData.scopes.length; iterator++) {
        const scopeAccountId = roleData.scopes[iterator].account;
        if (scopeAccountId == accountId) {
          userData.push({
            email: user[it].email,
            id: user[it].id,
          });
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return cb(null, userData);
  };
```

I want to change this program in a way such that I can fetch all the roles in which the given account id is present, but I can't find a way about how to apply that condition.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: provide sample data of roles and user

Comment: Actually, I found a way already. There is a way through which we can iterate in an array of objects in MongoDb. I just used that. Thanks, for reaching out.